# Why doesn't the nested flex parent height grow with children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjEpbj) the children overflow the parent height but why does the flex parent height not grow with children?

I can use `display:block` to achieve it, but I would want it to be flex.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.grand-parent{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  display:flex;
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:100%;
  flex-shrink:0;
  width:100%;
}

.child{
  height:1500px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.green{
  background:green;
}

.blue{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child green"></div>
    <div class="child blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the logical behavior and its how the algorithm of flexbox works. To start, let's remove some properties especially the `flex-shrink:0`.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.grand-parent{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  display:flex;
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.child{
  height:1500px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

.green{
  background:green;
}

.blue{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child green"></div>
    <div class="child blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As we can clearly see, we have **no overflow** because the algorithm will shrink the elements to fit their parent container.

---

Initially we have defined the `html,body` to be `height:100%` (it's ok) then we defined the `grand-parent` to be `height:100%` and a flex container with a **row direction** (it's ok). Then we made `.parent` element to be `min-height:100%` and since its a flex item its height will **be equal** to the height of its parent because the alignment is set by default to **stretch** (so `min-height:100%` is somehow useless in this case). We have also made the parent element to be a flex container with a **column direction**.

Now, let's consider the `child` elements. Their total height will exceed the height of their parent so they will shrink equally to fit inside it as this is the default behavior AND the parent will not grow with them even if you define `flex-shrink:0` on it because there is nothing to shrink for the parent element simply because its following a **row direction** inside his flex container and there is no width overflowing.

If you add `flex-shrink:0` to child they won't srink AND they will overflow their parent but will not force their parent to grow with them because the height of the parent is defined within its own flex container by the stretch behavior.

Now if you change the alignment of the `grand-parent` element, the parent element will grow because its height will now be defined with the height of its content and not the stretch behavior and you will also notice that `flex-shrink:0` will do nothing on the child elements:

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.grand-parent{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.child{
  height:1500px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.green{
  background:green;
}

.blue{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child green"></div>
    <div class="child blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very nicely explained. Any suggestions on where I can read in depth about flex?

Comment: @Flake check this guy : https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b .. if you want in depth explanation with link to official source you will find everything there, there is very good canonical answers about flexbox ;)